# Rails Test Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, rake-test

I keep getting these errors on terminal whenever i run the following code.

```
rake test  or bundle exec rake test

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Show your test code that's causing this.

Comment: Looks like the `guard` gem is not installed; try running `bundle install`.

Comment: i already did, but still tried it again. Still getting  the same error. And how do i install the guard gem do i just add  gem 'guard' to my gemfile..

Comment: @RailsOuter Here is the code they are still default nothing have been added                                                                                                      require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
  end

end

Comment: @PrakashMurthy.. Thanks man it worked, i added the gem file to the development group and it worked...but incase of other project which is best adding the guard gem to the development or test enviroment?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Please how do i mark as answered. This is actually my first question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `guard` is not installed/included in Gemfile. Include it in Gemfile if it is not already there. And run `bundle install`.

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard for how to use guard. https://github.com/guard/guard is also a good resource.